# PHAsset assetResourcesForAsset fails when called too often

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, phasset

I need to retrieve the names of all the `PHAsset` existing in the Camera Roll, individually and in a short time.
To get the file name, I use the documented `originalFilename` property of `PHAssetResource` associated to the `PHAsset`.
This works fine for the first assets, but at some point (after around 400 assets), it starts failing and returning `nil` every time.
Here is a code that shows this behavior (running on an iPhone 7 with ~800 photos in the Camera Roll):

```
PHFetchResult *result = [PHAssetCollection fetchAssetCollectionsWithType:PHAssetCollectionTypeSmartAlbum
subtype:PHAssetCollectionSubtypeSmartAlbumUserLibrary                                                                     options:nil];
PHAssetCollection *assetCollection = result.firstObject;
PHFetchResult *assetsFetchResult = [PHAsset fetchAssetsInAssetCollection:assetCollection options:nil];

for (int i = index; i<[assets count]; i++) {
    PHAsset *asset = assets[i];
    NSArray *resources = [PHAssetResource assetResourcesForAsset:asset];
    NSString *name = (resources.count > 0) ? [(PHAssetResource*)resources.firstObject originalFilename] : nil;
    NSLog(@"%i: %@", i, name);
}
```

When using undocumented methods to get the file name, such as `[asset valueForKey@"filenamme"]` or the `PHImageFileURLKey` key of the `info` dictionary returned by the `PHImageManager`, everything works well (although the name is different than with the `originalFilename` and well, it's not reliable since it's not documented).

How come the official method is that unreliable? 
Is there something I do wrong?

Comment: Use PHImageManager to get UIImage object from PHAsset

Comment: @KrishnaDattShukla I need the file name, how can I get it from the UIImage? (besides using the undocumented PHImageFileURLKey)

Comment: You can get everything from PHAsset by using code I just added in my answer..

Comment: @KrishnaDattShukla didn't find your answer here, could you please point out!? Did you mean your comment!?

Comment: see this - https://stackoverflow.com/a/41761879/5172413